# Using the state intercept in statsmodels MLEModel class for known exogenous inputs

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, statsmodels, state-space

The state intercept c_t in the [statsmodels statespace formulation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.representation.Representation.html) appears to be a way to interject exogenous control variables into the statespace framework. However, I can't get it to work. The simplest possible example I could think of was a mean model with known offsets from a baseline, combined with random noise. In statsmodels statespace notation, it would be:

a_t = 0 * a_{t - 1} + sin(pi * t / 24) + 0 * eta_t,

y_t = 30 + 1 * a_t + e_t,

where t = 0, ..., 999 and e_t ~ N(0, 4). You can see below how I attempted to implement this:

```
# Python 3.6.3, Statsmodels 0.9.0
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel import MLEModel

N = 1000
t = np.arange(N)
alpha = 2 * np.sin(np.pi * t / 24)
y = 30 + alpha + 2 * np.random.randn(N)

class Simple(MLEModel):
    start_params = [28, 2.2]
    param_names = ['int', 'sigma2_e']

    def __init__(self, endog, state_int):
        super().__init__(endog, k_states = 1)

        self.initialize_stationary()
        self.loglikelihood_burn = 100

        self['transition', 0, 0] = 0.0
        self['selection', 0, 0] = 0.0
        self['design', 0, 0] = 1.0

        self.state_intercept = np.reshape(state_int, (1, N))

    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)

        self['obs_intercept', 0, 0] = params[0]
        self['obs_cov', 0, 0] = params[1]

my_Simple = Simple(y, alpha)
mle_results = my_Simple.fit(method = 'nm', maxiter = 1000)
mle_results.summary()
```

If the estimation takes into account the offsets, then I'll expect to get a variance estimate of around 4. If it ignores them however, it will be higher do to the variation from the sinusoid. As you'll see when you run it, it is indeed higher.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use attribute-setting notation for state space system matrices with the `MLEModel` class, so your `self.state_intercept` call is failing. e.g. if you do:

```
print(mle_results.filter_results.state_intercept)
```

then you get:

```
[[0.]]
```

Instead, you should do:

```
self['state_intercept'] = np.reshape(state_int, (1, N))
```

and that gives a variance estimate around 4, as you expected.

Comment: Very cool. Just curious, would you feel comfortable using this method to add in a B*u(t) as in the equations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Linear_systems ? I suppose you'd have to lag the u(t). It feels like a hack but I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place in finding software to fit a state space model with control inputs.

Comment: Yes I think so - the model we have is essential the LQG control case (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic%E2%80%93Gaussian_control), and you can certainly set c(t) = B u(t).

Comment: For example, we do that in our VARMAX model, putting exogenous variables with estimated coefficients into the state intercept c(t)